# How to bind kendo ui mvc grid to a list of objects

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am trying to use the kendo ui mvc wrapper grid to bind to a list of objects.

In addition, I'm adding a checkbox to the first column of each row and the grid is wrapper in a form. I then want to take advantage of the default model binding for a (sequential or non-sequential) list when submitting.

The problem I am having is writing the **HiddenFor** and **CheckBoxFor** helper methods that are indexed.

If I was to write the table layout myself it would be something like this:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="hidden" name="Index" autocomplete="off" value="@i" />
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model[i].Id)
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => Model[i].Selected)
                </td>
                ...
```

This produces the below HTML output.

```
<input type="hidden" name="Index" autocomplete="off" value="0" />
<input id="[0].Id" name="[0].Id" type="hidden" value="1234" />
<input id="[0].Selected" name="[0].Selected" type="checkbox" value="true" />
<input name="[0].Selected" type="hidden" value="false" />
```

How is this possible with **Server** side binding using the kendo ui mvc grid wrapper?

I tried using a counter defined outside the grid and incrementing it both on .RowAction and inside the bound column but had mixed results which did not give me the desired result.

```
var counter = 0;
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
    .Name("grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(c => c.Id)
            .Template(
                @<text>
                    <input type="hidden" name="Index" autocomplete="off" value="@counter" />
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model[counter].Id)
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => Model[counter].Selected)
                </text>)
                ...
```

The problem I had was increment the counter. Maybe there is a better solution?

Another attempt I made was to write the table html myself and then apply the javascript grid binding $("grid").kendoGrid(...). However, I then loose the ability of defining css classes on my tr/td elements dynamically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this (untested):

```
var counter = -1;
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
    .Name("grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns
            .Bound(c => c.Id)
            .Template(
                @<text>
                    @{counter++;}
                    <input type="hidden" name="Index" autocomplete="off" value="@counter" />
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[counter].Id)
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m[counter].Selected)
                </text>);

        ... some other columns
    }
)
```

Comment: Works well incrementing counter using @{counter++;} in the end column. I could also start the incrementor from -1 and add the @{counter++;} for the 1st element in the 1st column thereby getting rid of the empty end column

Comment: Yes, good point. Feel free to update my answer with this better approach.